# QGIS point sampling tool error in extracting values

Tags: qgis, point, sampling

I am trying to use the point sampling tool plugin from QGIS to get some sea ice data (ranging from 0-1) from a GTiff raster layer (ESPG: 3411) for my sites (ESPG:4326) in the Arctic. But the sea ice values obtained are all **1.0000**.

I have set the project CRS as ESPG: 3411 (with OTF), same as the raster layer.

The overlay looks fine as I can actually click individual points on the QGIS to obtain sea ice data value point by point but I have hundreds of points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in the CRS. Layers geometry  **must be in same CRS** (like in other overlay analysis). OTF (*on the fly*) transformation doesn't matter since it not change the gometry in the layer file.

You have to reproject your point layer (Layer --> Save as..) or raster image (Raster --> Projections --> Warp (Reproject)... to same CRS.

In other words you are now probably sampling "empty space" and you have to fit your data in same CRS.

Comment: OTF **DOES** matter. Turning it off would show that the layers don't align. And the point sampling tool sees the data in the same way, without OTF.

Comment: @AndreJ Yes you'r right, it's definetly worth mentioning. I meant that OTF doesn't matter for sampling point tool itself (algorithm process) since OTF only visualize data in chosen CRS and not changing the geometry.